# How to recover from viewDidUnload(after memory warnings), using UISplitViewController

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

I'm making a split-view based iPad application(Portrait mode only), and I want to know how to recover initial state after `viewDidUnload` is called.

When split-view application started for the first time, 
`-splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:`
is called automatically (right after `-viewDidLoad`). 
I prepares UIBarButtonItems in the method.

If I open modal dialog or something with `UIWebViewController` (it consumes a lot of memory), application receives memory warning, `viewDidUnload`(s) are called.

When I close the modal dialog,  -viewDidLoad is called automatically, but this time 
`-splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` is not called.

I prepares UIBarButtonItems in 
`-splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:`
but it is not called, so buttons are dismissed.

In that case, should I call the method manually?

I found similar posting here.
https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController/issues/6

Thanks.

Comment: You should almost always configure your UI in viewDidLoad. Where do you put these UIBarButtonItems after you create them?

Comment: That is done in splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:  Could you create a split-view based project? You can find no implementation in viewDidLoad. I suppose it is because to change the buttons dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know it is OK to answer to my own question, but maybe I found an answer for this.
 http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2011-02/msg00430.html

It says that we should preserve BarButtonItems in viewDidUnload, and load it in viewDidLoad.

It seems working fine.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
   [super viewDidUnload];
   self.toolbarItems = self.toolbar.items; // property with retain policy
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   if (self.toolbarItems) {
      self.toolbar.items = self.toolbarItems;
      self.toolbarItems = nil;
   }
}
```